# Python- check value is within range infinity

Tags: python, range, infinity

I need to check if a value is within a range. 
Example,

```
actualVal1=-1.2
actualVal2=inf
rangeVal=3.6
```

`actualVal2` can be `inf` or `-inf`

I tried something like this but it didn't work.

Any suggestions how I can check if a val is within inf or -inf.

```
if actualVal1<rangeVal<float('inf')
```

Comment: *Which* value are you trying to check?  What is the point of `actualVal2`, when your attempted solution doesn't even use it?

Comment: There was an issue from the internal api. Thanks everyone for answering the question. Its resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the basic setup as best as I can understand your question:

```
from math import inf  # assuming Python 3.5 or later

lower_limit, upper_limit = -inf, inf

range_value = 3.6

if lower_limit < range_value < upper_limit:
    print("Within Range")
else:
    print("Outside Range")
```

Any `float` value that `range_value` takes on should pass this test.  As for the more limited range:

```
lower_limit, upper_limit = -1.2, inf
```

The example `range_value = 3.6` will pass this test.  But `range_value = -3.6` won't.  Is this what you're getting at?  If not, please consider a rework of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to know how to check whether a number is between -1.2 and infinite, or -1.2 and negative infinity. If that's the case, then:

```
if val > -1.2:
    print("infinity")
elif val < -1.2:
    print("negative infinity")
```